# Using rsync to query the checksum of a remote file

Tags: rsync, hashsum, checksum

Can we use rsync to simply get the checksum of a remote file, without transferring it?

This could be useful for verifying the integrity of remote files without using a lot of bandwidth, if you don't have a matching local file to compare with.  Also, in case you don't have full shell access to the remote machine (so you can't just log in and run `md5sum` or whatever), but do have rsync access through rsyncd, restricted ssh, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do

```
rsync --checksum --dry-run --checksum-choice=xxh128  --out-format="%C" host.example.com:/tmp/foo/hello.txt /dev/null
```

This writes the xxh128 checksum of the remote file `hello.txt` to standard output, in hex format (e.g. `6bba86c7e069f56d5a10b435f1c8e49c`).

Where:

- `--checksum` forces a checksum to be computed
- `--dry-run` prevents anything from being transferred
- `--checksum-choice=xxh128` requests use of the xxh128 hash algorithm.  You can also use `xxh64` or `md5` or various others, see `rsync --version` for those supported by your client.

  Note this only works if the remote server also supports the desired algorithm.  Some servers may not offer a choice at all.  I found one server (Synology NAS) that only supports md5, and uses it if `--checksum-choice` is not supplied, yet rejects `--checksum-choice-md5`.
- `--out-format="%C"` outputs the checksum only for each file that is transferred.  See the "log format" option in [rsyncd.conf(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf) for other information you can output.  Using `--out-format="%C  %f"` produces output in the same format as `xxh128sum`, which can be used as input to `xxh128sum --check` (respectively `md5sum`, etc).
- `/dev/null` is just to have something to stand in as a local destination file.  If you do not give a destination file then rsync just lists the remote file, but does not ask the remote server for a checksum.

You can also give a pattern matching multiple remote files, or use `-r` to recursively checksum all files in a directory tree.  In this case, replace the `/dev/null` destination with the name of an existing local directory, such as `/tmp`.  It will not be written to.

Note that the remote rsync may checksum all the files before generating any response, which may be a problem if there are timeouts.